# Node save returning 500

Tags: node.js, express, react-router, mern

I am trying to complete a MERN course on Udemy, and I got stuck on user authentication.

For this section, I am using Insomnia to conduct various requests, and for some reason, I am not getting the same results as the tutorial.

Here is my userRouter.js code:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {email, password, passwordVerify} = req.body;
    
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({email});

     if (existingUser) {
       return res.status(400).json({
       errorMessage: "An account with the email already exists.",
       });
     }
     
     const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
     const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

     const newUser = new User({
       email,
       passwordHash,
     });

     // the below 2 lines seems to be the cause of the error
     const savedUser = await newUser.save();
     res.send(savedUser); 
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

As indicated above, the last two lines of the try block is where the code fails. I am able to console.log(newUser) to see the newUser.

But the newUser.save() is where the code fails.

I am unsure if this is necessary, but here is the userModel.js file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    passwordHas: {type: String, required: true},
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

According to the tutorial, as long as the email and password don't already exist, I should see the following:

[image]

But instead, I am getting a 500 error, and I am not sure why.  There are no visible errors in the terminal console.

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your model you have declared it as `passwordHas` but when you are creating a new user object you are creating a property named `passwordHash` .

```
const newUser = new User({
       email,
       passwordHash,
     });
```

The above would generate these properties:

```
{email: 'request parameter email', passwordHash: 'generated password hash'}
```

Either modify it here:

```
const newUser = new User({
       email,
       passwordHas : passwordHash,
     });


or change the name in your model from `passwordHas` to `passwordHash`.
```

Comment: A typo was causing my error.  Unbelievable.  This cost my a whole day.  Thank you for pointing out something so simple.  I do appreciate it.